# How to transform the string of this input into numbers?

Tags: python, math, numbers, calculator

```
from math import *

print("force  a to b")
Fa = input("Force a : ")
Fb = input("Force b : ")
distance = input("distance : ")

k = 9*10**9
Fa = float(Fa)
Fb = float(Fb)
distance = float(distance)

def force(Fa, Fb, distance):
    force = k * (Fa * Fb) / (distance)**2
    print(force)

force(Fa, Fb, distance)
```

The error I get:

```
script> python force.py
force a to  b
Force a : 1,6*10**-19
Force b :  -1.6*10**-19
distance : 0.053*10**-9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rakot\Documents\math\script\force.py", line 9, in <module>
    Fa = float(Fa)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1,6*10**-19'
```

I guess these kinds of numbers `"1, 6*10**-19"` are not float numbers — so my question is what types of numbers are they and how do I transform the string of the input into a type that allows me to do mathematical operations?

Comment: Use the scientific notation format for Python directly, this isn't a calculator, it won't interpret arbitrary maths expressions. Try something like `1.6e-19`.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are not entering the numbers correctly.

in your input try:
1.6e-19 instead of 1,6*10**-19

Answer (score 0):

```
print("force  a to b")
Fa = float(input("Force a : "))
a = float(input("Force a : "))
Fb = input("Force b : ")
b = input("Force b : ")
distance = input("distance 1: ")
distance2 = input("distance 2: ")
distance3 = input("distance 3: ")

k = 9*10**9
Fa = Fa*10**a
Fb = Fb*10**b
distance = distance*disrance2**distance3

def force(Fa, Fb, distance):
force = k * (Fa * Fb) / (distance)**2
print(force)

force(Fa, Fb, distance)
```

You have to get the parts of the math function that you are calculating one by one and put them in variables then you can apply a calculations on them, and you have to use `.` instead of `,` in float numbers.

Comment: I don't consider this to be a good solution. You're changing the user interface, and it would make it a worse experience to use. Also, the middle number will always be 10, they're using scientific notation.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

input() always returns a string. In the forth line you also get a string. You can count what's inside it using eval() function:
`Fb = eval(input("Force b : "))`

Don't use ',' in float, but '.', otherwise there will be an error

Comment: Do not use `eval()`, `exec()` or even `ast.literal_eval()` unless evaluation is the only way. [Thomas Jager](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5567382/thomas-jager) in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70906423/10824407#comment125349655_70906423) provided a proper format for numbers in scientific notation.

Comment: @olvin-roght Why on earth?

Comment: It's unsafe. It's bad practice. Exceptions are hard to handle. There're dozen of reasons why not to use evaluation.

Comment: @olvin-roght there still will be a mistake in his answer. Try the code yourself

Comment: `float("1.6e-19")` works like a charm.

Comment: @thomas-jager yes, but it's a little console program - what can happen? And if eval was invented, than there was a reason for doing so

Comment: @thomas-jager 
g = '1.6e10-19'
g = float(g)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1.6e10-19'

Comment: I have seen just 2 examples for all the time when `eval()` have been used on purpose and made code run faster. It was in sources of some ORM where they constructed python expression as a replacement of complicated SQL. Even there was hundreds of conditional statements which validated constructed expression and reacted on all possible exceptions. `eval()` is a tool which you should avoid until you get to the point when you feel that it's the best option *(generally it never happens)*.

Comment: `1.6e10-19` is a wrong expression, what number are you trying to represent?

Comment: @plus2679 You don't include the 10 when writing numbers like that.